# How to invert a query in mongodb: $not

Tags: mongodb

The [mongo documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/) says the $not operator does what I want, but it doesn't seem to be working:

The following returns a single document:

```
db.user.find({_id:ObjectId("51f09113cc0bd4a4a3958c96")})
```

This returns all 27 documents:

```
db.user.find()
```

This returns no documents:

```
db.user.find({$not:{_id:ObjectId("51f09113cc0bd4a4a3958c96")}})
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `$ne`:

`db.user.find({"_id" : {$ne: ObjectId("51f09113cc0bd4a4a3958c96") }})`

Comment: Got it, thanks! Tho extra special points if you can also concisely explain why my thought model about this is wrong and when to use $not

Comment: @BT `$not` comes in conjunction with another operator [see docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/not/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `$ne`

```
db.user.find(_id: {$ne: ObjectId("51f09113cc0bd4a4a3958c96")})
```